# Cant make a logo turn on click in a accordion tab

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try, I just cant get the icon to turn on click.

Here I've posted my code for the section, ok so I want the `label::after` to rotate 90deg when you click on the label, here is what I'm mainly using:

`#accordion label + input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after`

I had the same one, but instead of label::after it was .content, the .content one worked normally but as soon as I try to use anything regarding the label itself it doesn't work at all, can some please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```css
#accordion {
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}

#accordion li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: none;
}

#accordion li label {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#accordion .content {
  background: none;
}

#accordion .content li p {
  background: none;
}

#accordion label+input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#accordion .content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 26px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

#accordion label+input[type="radio"]:checked+.content {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#accordion label:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0062cc;
  transition: ease all 0.35s;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

#accordion .tab-close {
  width: 35%;
}

#accordion label::after {
  content: "\276F";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

#accordion label+input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<section class="quantity" id="Quantity">
  <div class="services-container">
    <div class="quantity-left">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Quantity Surveying</h1>
        <p>
          We at BGQS Consulting strive to offer the highest quality QS service in SA and our main objective is to maintain the highest possible standards with regards to: Services to the client, Effectiveness and competence, Integrity, secrecy, honesty and loyalty,
          Quality of documentation, Experience and scope of knowledge, Application of the latest technology, Professionalism and true commitment, Punctuality and response time and Friendliness. Here are some of the steps in our process:
        </p>
        <ul id="accordion">
          <li>
            <label for="quantity-first">Estimations</label>
            <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="quantity-first">
            <div class="content">
              <ul>
                <li>Preparing capital cost estimates for budget purposes and project approval through all the phases pre-concept to feasibility.</li>
                <li>Creating a compilation of budget cost though our in-house database of previously completed projects, quotations from equipment and special services suppliers.</li>
                <li>Conducting preliminary measures and elemental cost estimating.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="quantity-second">Pre-Contract Services</label>
            <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="quantity-second">
            <div class="content">
              <ul>
                <li>Preparing contract conditions, including special conditions.</li>
                <li>Standardisation of contract conditions and special conditions for any particular project</li>
                <li>Preparing tender bills of quantities for all construction contracts (e.g., civils, building, demolition works, structural, mechanical, piping, electrical and instrumentation, etc.)</li>
                <li>Assistance with compilation of vendor lists for client approval.</li>
                <li>Drafting of enquiry documents for tender purposes.</li>
                <li>Commercial tender evaluations, clarifications and adjudication reports.</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `<label>` element is below the radio `<input>` in the HTML, so in terms of styling, the label cannot infer when the input is "*checked*" or not. Lets fix it:

```css
#accordion {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 0;
}

#accordion li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: none;
}

#accordion li label {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#accordion .content {
  background: none;
}

#accordion .content li p {
  background: none;
}

#accordion label+input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#accordion .content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 26px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

/* Changhed + to ~ since the order of HTML changed */
#accordion input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .content {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#accordion label:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0062cc;
  transition: ease all 0.35s;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

#accordion .tab-close {
  width: 35%;
}

#accordion label::after {
  content: "\276F";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s; /* transition should be here and not below */
}

#accordion input[type="radio"]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul id="accordion">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" hidden name="accordion" id="quantity-first" />
    <label for="quantity-first">Estimations</label>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>Preparing capital cost estimates for budget purposes and project approval through all the phases pre-concept to feasibility.</li>
        <li>Creating a compilation of budget cost though our in-house database of previously completed projects, quotations from equipment and special services suppliers.</li>
        <li>Conducting preliminary measures and elemental cost estimating.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" hidden name="accordion" id="quantity-second" />
    <label for="quantity-second">Pre-Contract Services</label>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>Preparing contract conditions, including special conditions.</li>
        <li>Standardisation of contract conditions and special conditions for any particular project</li>
        <li>Preparing tender bills of quantities for all construction contracts (e.g., civils, building, demolition works, structural, mechanical, piping, electrical and instrumentation, etc.)</li>
        <li>Assistance with compilation of vendor lists for client approval.</li>
        <li>Drafting of enquiry documents for tender purposes.</li>
        <li>Commercial tender evaluations, clarifications and adjudication reports.</li>
      </ul>
```

I advise using input of type `checkbox` and not `radio` because `radio` accordion items cannot be "closed/collapsed" unless another item is "opened". for UX, it's better to use type `checkbox` .

Comment: Thank you so very much! Been struggling on this for a while now, and started to pull out my hairs, I actually had this in a checkbox format once, but my boss told me he wanted it to only have one tab open at the time, and have the rest close automatically, and all of the examples that I saw used radio buttons